# what is measured in units of sat/kw?

Tags: transaction-fees, terminology, block-weight

Whilst learning about bitcoin & lightning fees I have encountered the abbreviation sat/kw a few times, most recently here:

[Why can’t lightning tx’s be signed with sighash single to allow for fee updates?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/83135/why-can-t-lightning-tx-s-be-signed-with-sighash-single-to-allow-for-fee-updates?r=SearchResults&s=1|46.6782)

Is it a ratio of satoshis per kilowatt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that James is using "sat/kw", to refer to "satoshi per kiloweightunit" as a means to express the fee rate of a transaction. "Weight" here refers to what replaced "blocksize" as a blockspace limit in the protocol rules with the segwit softfork.

I'm seeing "sat/kw" for the first time in this context. I've seen `wu` used before to refer to weightunits instead of `w`, but the related unit "virtual bytes `vB`" seems to be more common in the context of feerates generally.

I've explained the relationship of blocksize, virtual size, and weight in depth here: [Is there a difference between bytes and virtual bytes (vbytes)?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/89385/5406)

Comment: Actually in the BOLTs, kw is used to calculate fees for commitment transactions. So I think Jannes picked up "sat/kw" from there.